# How does RFB and X11 protocols work together?

Tags: x11, framebuffer, vnc, xvfb, rfb-protocol

I am trying to understand how a VNC works using X11 and RFB protocols.

I see my XVnc process listens on 59xx(RFB), 58xx(HTTP) and 60xx(X11) ports.

- *I do not know what is HTTP for, but I think we can exclude that
  from picture and still can understand how Xvnc uses RFB and X11 protocols.*
- From the definition in here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143, I understand that RFB protocol is for remote access through GUI and which uses framebuffers.
- Each client session has a dedicated framebuffer which is accessed by client, modified on client request and updates on it are sent to client.
- X11 is this protocol is to display any GUI applications like it tells how to display a window or text etc.

So, is my following understand correct?

- The client communicates to server on :59xx port using RFB protocol
  and sends any requests.
- The requests are then processed by a component of Xvnc service running on :59xx port and a request to :60xx port is created in X11 protocol.
- The Xvnc service component on :60xx port then provides an output and is processed by Xvnc service and updates the frame buffer.
- The update is sent to client in RFB protocol in simplest way using different methods to reduce network data.